# Subseries of harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is well known that harmonic series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$ diverges but in 1985 G. H. Behforooz proved that if we remove terms that have denominator that ends with $9$ series converges. To which constant does that series converge? What is special about numbers that end in $9$?

Comment: Could you please give a reference?  I don't understand what the assertion is that Behforooz proved.

Comment: I think you mean "if we remove all terms where the denominator has a $9$ in its base $10$ decimal expansion, then the series converges."  The series most certainly still diverges if we remove only those numbers which end with a $9$.

Comment: The number $9$ is special. For example, cats have $9$ lives. But there is nothing special about $9$ for this problem. And it is not "ends in $9$", that does not affect divergence.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series

Comment: @Byron. I think that link is very helpful. Thank you

Comment: I found a reference to H (not G H) Behforooz in 1995 (not 1985): http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/HarmonicSeries.shtml --- many other links arise from typing *behforooz harmonic* into the web.

Comment: G Hossein Behforooz wrote an article called "Thinning out the harmonic series" that appeared in the October 1995 issue of *Mathematics Magazine*, the MAA publication.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, please write up your insights as an answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Overhere, cats have 7 lives...